# Examples of compact Lie group with infinite volume?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

The book I'm reading says the quotient of a semi-simple group by its maximal triangularizable subgroup can fail to have finite volume. For the case of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ I'm not really seeing it. In the KAN decomposition the maximal triangular subgroup is AN, and compact subgroup is $K\simeq SO(n)$ which has finite volume.

Is there any intuitive way of understanding when do such situations happen?

Comment: For the volume of a (simple) compact Lie group $G$ there is a formula, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.3031.pdf). But you are talking about a quotient?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, and maybe a reasonable explanation?

Comment: Yes, I would also need a reasonable explanation. The volume of a compact Lie group (in your title) should be finite, or not? Any compact manifold $G$ has finite volume with respect to any Riemannian metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is somewhat misleading: it is any easy exercise to show every compact Lie group has finite (Haar) volume.

You are correct that for the Iwasawa decomposition $G=KAN$ the quotient $G/AN$ is diffeomorphic to $K$; the issue is that $K$ *need not be compact*. $K$ is the maximal compact subgroup if the center of $G$ is finite, but without this requirement it may not be.

As a counterexample, take $G=\widetilde{\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}$ to be the universal cover of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, a connected semisimple group for which $K\cong\mathbb{R}$.